# Normal Distribution in Stochastic Calculus, MATLAB: how to find probability?

Tags: matlab, distribution, calculus, stochastic, volatility

I am currently revising for my computational finance exam in a computer science course and got stuck on this question:

Let **S** be the price of a share with the yearly drift rate `μ = 0.25` and the yearly volatility `σ = 0.5`. Suppose that the share is worth `S0 = 80p` now. Calculate the **probability** that the share will `go down by 10p or more` in `a year`: express it through **N, the distribution function for φ (0, 1)** and calculate it numerically.

I know how normal distribution works but I don't know how this version of it works.

I was given the equation below to help me find my answer but I don't know how to apply it.

**Stochastic differential equation**: lnST – lnS0 ~ φ [(μ – σ^2/2) T, σ^2T]

I plugged in the numbers and came out with:

```
lnS1 ~ φ [4.50703, 0.25]
```

I also tried:

```
mean price = 80
σ = 0.5
below price = 70

X ~ N(80, 0.5)
Z = (70 – 80)/0.5 = -20
P(X ≤ 70) = P(Z ≤ = -20)
```

But I couldn't find data for 20 standard deviations in the normal distribution table. Anyone know how this works? Also, is there a way to calculate this on MATLAB?

Comment: You may want to ask this in http://math.stackexchange.com/ here.